# VSTS Build With Local Nuget Package From Local Nuget Server

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuget-server, azure-devops

Has anyone had success building an ASPNET5 application in VSTS with a local (not public facing) Nuget server as a feed? Following these steps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5 I can see the script restoring but it always errors out on my local package. I am sure I am configuring something wrong. This is what I have tried:

1. Add a Nuget Installer task with a arg to my solution and NuGet arguments `nugete.exe -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/;http://mynugetserver"` (and I tried including no Nuget arguments and including a Nuget.config in the root of my solution). However, the build runs into a an exception saying it cant find the local url: `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mydomain'`. Okay I understand that, but I do I get it to recognize a local URL?
2. After researching I thought I would have to use the Package Manager Extension for VSTS. So I loaded my packaged on there successfully, but when I included that package URL in my Nuget.config I get a bunch of unauthorized responses from the `PreBuild.ps1` because it is trying to look at the VSTS package URL too. And that is where I am now.

Current Nuget.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
      </packageRestore>
      <config>
        <!--DO I NEED TO INCLUDE MY PROXY INFOR HERE I AM BEHIND ONE AT WORK-->
      </config>
      <bindingRedirects>
        <add key="skip" value="False" />
      </bindingRedirects>
      <activePackageSource>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
      </activePackageSource>
      <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <add key="Local" value="https://vstsurl/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Local/nuget/v3/index.json" />
<add key="Company Nuget Gallery v2" value="http://mydomain/nuget/api/v2" />
      </packageSources>
    </configuration>
```

**UPDATE**

if I use the Package Manager on VSTS these are the warnings / exceptions all which seem to come from the local feed. not sure why it is using the local feed for all the external packages

```
 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
... other exceptions here
          ----------
    Restore failed
```

Comment: Is `mydomain` available to the internet?

Comment: That is the problem. How VSTS server should reach your intranet? you need to publish the feed somewhere internet-accessible

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the build agent hosted by VSTS and your nuget server is in local (Cannot access from internet), the package restore will fail since the build agent cannot find your nuget server. You'd either configure your nuget server so that it can be accessed from internet or deploy your own build agent in the same intranet with your nuget server.

Comment: that is what I thought. Have you played around with the new package extensions for VSTS? I feel like that is the way to go

Comment: @JayMichael Yes, that's a good option for private nuget server.